# C++: Reading txt file through fstream

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, fstream

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
Toy ball
1.25
DVD
20.00
Row Boat
1.00
```

The first line is the item, the second is the price, and it repeats for the next 2 items and so on. So my question is how can i take the first line and put it in a string, and the second line and put it in a float value? Here is the code i have, i am using structs.

```
const int TOTAL_ITEMS = 3;
for (int itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < TOTAL_ITEMS; itemNumber++) {
        string line;
        getline(inFile,line);
        list[itemNumber].item = line;
        float cost;
        inFile >> cost;
        list[itemNumber].price = cost;
}
```

I then print the list:

```
for (int itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < TOTAL_ITEMS; itemNumber++) {
    cout << itemNumber << ": " << list[itemNumber].item <<  " " << list[itemNumber].price << endl;
```

Now this doesnt print what i want it to, the struct array only took in the first line and the first price and printed it out, but the others all said "0". Any help would be awesome. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float` input (by the way, just use `double`, less trouble) leaves a newline in the input buffer, which is consumed by the subsequent line input.

Instead, use `getline` for both lines.

Then use e.g. `istringstream` to convert the second line to ... `double`, just by "reading" from it in the same as you'd read from `inFile`.

---

In addition to that direct bug fix, you need to check the stream state of `inFile`, e.g. by calling its `fail` member function. When you use the stream object directly as a condition, its conversion to `bool` calls `fail` for for you, and negates the result so that the stream object itself denotes "not fail". Note that `good` is *not* the opposite of `fail`, and also note that a fail state is persistent and causes subsequent input operations to be ignored.

Comment: Just FYI, this solution of using getline and then a stringstream to turn the line into a number will have fairly poor performance.  Just using fscanf would be quite a bit faster, or perhaps getline followed by strtod.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the stream state as you consume input.  You can do that by checking the return value of getline() and operator>>:

```
if (!getline(inFile,line))
    ; // oops, error, do something

if (!(inFile >> cost))
    ; likewise
```

Once you do this you will find that your input is failing because you're reading things slightly incorrectly, but it shouldn't be hard to fix once you see where it's broken.

Comment: i am able to put in breakpoints to see what the program inputs step by step and i think the problem is that when the program takes in the price it doesn't skip to the next line. So it reads "Toy Ball" and then it reads "1.75" but then it gets the line after "1.75" which is "" because it is the next line that has "DVD"

Comment: Correct.  I'm not quite sure how you're not quite sure what I mean--I gave you the verbatim code to check for the errors that you need to check.  Make your code look more like mine, and run your program, and you will detect the errors.

Comment: Well your code just tells me where there is an error. I know where there is an error. My problem is i dont know how to fix it. I know whats wrong, my question is simple, how do i fix it?